# Upgrading from Django 1.5.5 to Django 1.8.5

Tags: python, django

I have to use Django 1.8.5 since support for 1.5.5 has ended on webfaction and 1.4.22 won't work. Here's the error log I've got now that I'm using 1.8.5

```
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=963728): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 52, in load_middleware
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     mw_instance = mw_class()
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/redirects/middleware.py", line 18, in __init__
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     if not apps.is_installed('django.contrib.sites'):
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py", line 231, in is_installed
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     self.check_apps_ready()
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
[Mon Nov 09 19:03:25 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

And the wsgi which likely needs to be edited to work with django 1.8.5

```
"""
WSGI config for kb project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""

import os
import sys

# http://generics7.blogspot.com/2014/06/setup-new-relic-with-webfaction-django.html

#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kb.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
#from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#application = get_wsgi_application()
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kb.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

I'm all for upgrading if it fixes the issue but not if doesn't. When I tried to use 1.4.22 I got this error

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.kenyabuzz.com/?device=browser

Django Version: 1.4.22
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'memcache_status',
 'djangorestframework',
 'haystack',
 'lamusoftware.generic',
 'mptt',
 'bootstrapform',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'south',
 'oauth2client',
 'articles',
 'banners',
 'common',
 'directory',
 'events',
 'galleries',
 'marketplace',
 'movies',
 'pages',
 'profiles',
 'search',
 'stats',
 'minidetector',
 'mobile',
 'reports',
 'favorites',
 'braces',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'wordofmouth',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_mobile',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.RedirectMovie')


Traceback:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  87.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/middleware/log_ip_middleware.py" in process_request
  65.         if request.user.is_authenticated():
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  184.             self._setup()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  248.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in <lambda>
  17.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in get_user
  9.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_user
  98.         user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in __getitem__
  39.         return self._session[key]
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_session
  172.                 self._session_cache = self.load()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in load
  19.                 expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  131.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  358.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  624.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  642.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1250.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
  1122.                     process_extras=process_extras)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in setup_joins
  1304.                 field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/options.py" in get_field_by_name
  311.                 cache = self.init_name_map()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/options.py" in init_name_map
  341.         for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/options.py" in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
  429.             cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/options.py" in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
  443.         for klass in get_models(only_installed=False):
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py" in get_models
  181.         self._populate()
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py" in _populate
  67.                     self.load_app(app_name)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/loading.py" in load_app
  88.             models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/articles/models.py" in <module>
  10. from profiles.models import CustomUser
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/profiles/models.py" in <module>
  1. from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name AbstractBaseUser
```

It's because AbstractBaseUser isn't defined in django 1.4.22 and I recon importing all those and making sure they work is a lot more harder than upgrading.

**UPDATE**

I've edited the wsgi.py to look like below and restarted the server.

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kb.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm getting an error

```
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=981324): Target WSGI script '/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=981324): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     django.setup()
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/lib/python2.7/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Mon Nov 09 19:25:37 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Answer (score 0):

Your upgrade path is far far too long, and if you have any extra apps you are using they have probably undergone significant changes.

Instead, do a staged upgrade like below:

```
1.5 -> 1.6
1.6 -> 1.7
1.7 -> 1.8
```

It will take a while, but thats the price of leaving such a vital upgrade for so long.

Comment: I managed to get it working for 1.7 with a few minor bugs I'm fixing